# Show an element if date is before or after another date using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, momentjs

I'm using vue to dynamically show elements (called boxes) on the page, but I need to display an element based on if it's start date is before or after today+1 week.

So if the `box.start_date` is before one week from today, then show it, else hide it.

I'm not sure how I can do this in vue

ie.

```
<div class="box" v-if="box.start_date < *** 1 week from now date here?? ***"> ...  </div>
```

I tried using moment.js but it give me an error saying moment is not defined in vue

With laravel and blade I would just do this like this...

```
@if($box->start_date > now()->addWeek(1))
```

How can I make this work with vue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use a computed property to return that value :

```
computed:{
   beforeWeek(){
   return (new Date().getTime())-(new Date(this.box.start_date).getTime())> (7*24*60*60*1000)
   }
}
```

template :

```
<div class="box" v-if="beforeWeek"> ...  </div>
```

or you could a method :

```
methods:{
beforeWeek(start_date){
   return (new Date().getTime())-(new Date(start_date).getTime())> (7*24*60*60*1000)
   }
}
```

template :

```
<div class="box" v-if="beforeWeek(box.start_date)"> .... </div>
```

**Note : **

**7*24*60*60*1000** is the number of milliseconds in one week

Comment: You're on to something except box is actually within a loop `box in boxes`

Comment: you could use a method as i did in my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution that works for me using a method

```
<div class="box" v-if="skippableDate(box.start_date)"> .... </div>
```

And in my js

```
methods: {
        skippableDate(date){
            var now = new Date();
            var skippableDate = now.setDate(now.getDate() + (4+(7-now.getDay())) % 7) // this is getting next thursday (update 4 to the number of the day of the week you want)
            var parseDate = Date.parse(date);

            if(parseDate > skippableDate){
                return true
            }else{
                return false
            }
        },
},
```

Comment: uses `computed property` will be better in this situation. because the computed property will not be re-calc unless its reactivity is triggered. if uses `method`, it will be executed at every time of render.